# Where does one find the total number of context switches performed since bootup?

Tags: cpu, proc, process-management

I figured out that the number of context switches performed by a process can be found in `/proc/$$/status`. I have been trying to look for the total number of context switches performed since bootup.

I tried doing `grep context * | grep switch` while in `/proc`, and got the following output

```
...
kallsyms:0000000000000000 t xen_end_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 T paravirt_start_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 T paravirt_end_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 T nr_context_switches
kallsyms:0000000000000000 T rcu_note_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 r __ksymtab_rcu_note_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 r __kstrtab_rcu_note_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 D event_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 D event_class_ftrace_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 t ftrace_define_fields_context_switch
kallsyms:0000000000000000 T __event_context_switch
...
```

Could not make sense of this file upon opening. I also tried `grep -s -r context | grep switch`, but it appeared to be taking too much time.
Could not find a `man` entry for `kallsyms`.

So, where can I find the total number of context switches made since bootup and what could I have done to find it out on my own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of switches performed by each processor can be found in `proc/sched_debug`.

The output of `grep nr_switches *` is

```
...
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2652089
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2677660
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2778421
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2467321
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2527589
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2511760
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2528093
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2584352
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2570571
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2678180
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2381052
sched_debug:  .nr_switches                   : 2535081
...
```

The number of such lines printed will obviously depend on the number of logical cores on your machine.